# Edit - How to fix this if else statement variable issue?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to make a random number game but the condition is always false even though I added the b = input box statement

```
Option Explicit

dim b,a,max,min
'To randomize variable (a)
max=3
min=1
Randomize
a = (Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min))
b = inputbox("Guess a number from " & min & " to " & max)
If a = b Then
    msgbox("you win")
Else 
    msgbox("you died it was " & a)
End If
```

I expected when you guessed the right number it would say you when but it always you died the number was #

Comment: You never initialized `b`; its value is always zero and `a`'s value is never zero, hence, the condition `(a = b)` would always evaluate to false.

Comment: As @AhmedAbdelhameed has said you need to provide a value for `b` if that is what the user is expected to input, easiest way would be an `InputBox()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there but as has [been mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553692/how-to-fix-this-if-else-statement-variable-issue/55556936#comment97808680_55553692) you do not populate the variable be with a values so the comparison will always be `False`.

If you are expecting `b` to be populated by the user you could ask for input via the `InputBox()` function by adding one line;

```
Option Explicit

Dim beans, b, a, max, min
'To randomize variable (a)
max = 100
min = 1
Call Randomize()
'Enter the line below to collect input from the user.
b = InputBox("Enter a number between " & min & " and " & max & ".")
'Remember to round the number to make sure you have a whole number.
a = Round((Int((max - min + 1) * Rnd() + min)))
If (a = b) Then
    Call MsgBox("You win")
Else 
    Call MsgBox("You died it was " & a)
End If
```

You might also consider validating the input to make sure that the user enters a value between your `min` and `max` and responding accordingly if the value is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This matches 1 - 10.

```
Randomize
Num = Int((10 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
If CInt(Inputbox("Enter Number")) = Num Then
    Msgbox "match"
Else
    Msgbox "Nope it was " & Num
End If
```

The formula from help is `Int((upperbound - lowerbound + 1) * Rnd + lowerbound)`. See http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe.

Comment: If your formula is correct (upperbound - lowerbound) then your example matches 1-10, not 1-5 as you have stated?

Comment: 1-10 was too many to test. So I changed my test program to 1-5.

Comment: Apart from the `InputBox()` this answer adds no value, the OPs formula is correct in fact they use variables instead of literals which would be my prefered approach.

Comment: Variables should NEVER be used in place of constants or litterals. His programming was substandard.

Comment: @Noodles what are you talking about? The OP has used `Option Explicit` whereas in your sample you don't even bother to declare `Num`, remind me again, who's programming seems substandard?